# starting an activity stops android service

Tags: java, android, android-service

i have an android service that plays music.i start in my main activity with this code:

```
Intent service = new Intent(MainMenu.this, musicservice.class);
MainMenu.this.startService(service);
```

and this is my service:

```
public class musicservice extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    MediaPlayer mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(musicservice.this, R.raw.music);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });   
    mp.start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

it stsrts work fine, but when i start another activity, my music goes off and seems my service destroys!! but dont want this, i want my service only stops when my application ends. music plays only when user works with app. even when app in in the background i want my music dont play!  how i can implement this?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want the music to stop playing as soon as you start another Activity? Or do you want it to keep on playing when you've started another Activity? I'm asking this question because of the reply you've given TGMCians. Initially, I was thinking that TGMCians had misunderstood your question, but based on your reply to him -- I'm not so sure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your application to play music while your activity is on, try [bind it](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

it should look something like this:

Service:

```
package com.example.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.example.playmusic.R;

public class PlayMusicService extends Service {

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public PlayMusicService getService() {
            return PlayMusicService.this;
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        player.start();

    }

    public void pause() {
        player.pause();
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
package com.example.playmusic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.example.service.PlayMusicService;
import com.example.service.PlayMusicService.LocalBinder;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private PlayMusicService service;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    service.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (service != null) {
        service.play();
    } else {
        bindService();
    }
}

    private void bindService() {
        bindService(new Intent(this, PlayMusicService.class), new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                service = null;

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
                LocalBinder localBinder = (LocalBinder) binder;
                service = localBinder.getService();
                service.play();

            }
        }, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Service destroy when your activity destroy when you start service from activity.

Use `AlarmManager` to schedule the service repeatedly.

Comment: then i have to start my service from where?

Comment: Farhad, Assuming you really want your music to keep on playing when another Activity has begun (which is the direction TGMCians is going towards I think). You'll want start a separate thread from your Activity, which will in turn start the music service from that thread. But to make it easy for your users to stop that music once your Activity is no longer visible, it's common to allow your user to stop the music from the notification area below the status bar/action bar, and/or to stop the music service when the user unplugs his headphones.